# Can't resolve 'webgi' in 'C:\Users\coder\OneDrive\Desktop\first code\reactpr\practapp\src\component' What is the mistake?

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

[What is the possible mistake ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cVBG.png)

I export a 3d model from sketchfab and watching tutorials from freecodecamp.org react 3d iphone website . What is the error in setup that telling module not find can't resolve webgi in specified directory.

What should I do now?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.